# Growl notifications with Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, growl

Is it possible to configure Mail.app to use the growl notifications for incoming mail ?

Maybe there is an external script doing that too ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to download [GrowlMail](http://growl.info/growlmail/), however every time MacOS X is updated the version of GrowlMail becomes outdated and won't run (under Snow Leopard, at least).

I think that the current version of GrowlMail doesn't work with Mac OS X 10.6.7 at present. Details of why it keeps breaking are [here](http://growl.info/documentation/growlmail.php#growlmail-and-snow-leopard). It is annoying but seems unavoidable.

Comment: But a fix can found here: http://langui.sh/2011/03/21/fixing-growlmail-in-10-6-7-mail-4-5/

Comment: @Rene @LudoMC Didn't know about the patch.... that's useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

Growl is great, but there's a standalone extension that adds way more functionality to Mail.app. It's called Herald: http://erikhinterbichler.com/software/herald/

Herald is continuing the awesome tradition of Mail.appetizer, if you remember that one from a few years ago. It is superior.

Comment: You should rephrase your answer so that it looks like a real answer to the original question and not a reply to @Mikey's answer (even if you mention it). Anyways, thanks for the link !

Answer (score 0):

I outlined my method of using Growl in conjunction with Apple Mail, mail rules and AppleScript here: [Is there any way to get a pop-up notification on my iPhone or iPad when mail arrives?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-pop-up-notification-on-my-iphone-or-ipad-when-mail-arri/21027#21027)

The code for the AppleScript is also included in the answer I provided.